# How can a power adapter have higher output current than input?

Tags: power-supply

I have a USB power adapter for a speaker.  The specs on it say:

Input: 100-240v-50/60Hz  0.4A

Output: 5V 2000mA

Question:

Isn't 2000mA the same as 2A?

If so, how is that possible?

Comment: Very similar to the way a transmission provides more output torque at the wheels than the input torque where the transmission connects to the engine.

Comment: When a PSU steps down voltage, it steps up current. Otherwise it is very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about **power** supplies is that it is about the **power**, not the current.

Power is the product of current and voltage.  \$P = E \times I\$ where P is power in watts, E is voltage in volts, and I is current in amperes.

You have an output of \$5V \times 2A = 10W\$.

The input is \$ 100V \times 0.4A = 40W\$

Your power supply is taking in 40 watts at 100 V to deliver 10 watts at 5 volts.

You are getting less out than you put in, so nothing is being mysteriously created.

How it actually does it involves a lot of complicated stuff.  Given the level of the question, I don't think a description of the electronics is going to help.

You can see from the specifications that the output voltage is (much) lower than the input voltage.  The power supply trades off voltage to get current.

It's kind of like a garden hose with a sprayer nozzle.

If you have a garden hose connected to a water faucet on one end and with a sprayer nozzle on the other end, then the water will spray out and go halfway across the yard.

If you take the nozzle off and just let the water run out of the hose, the pressure is far lower but more water per second will flow out of the hose compared to the nozzle.  The water doesn't shoot across the yard without the nozzle, but more water comes out.

Removing the nozzle trades pressure (voltage) for a higher flow rate (current.)

Your power supply trades pressure (voltage) to get a higher flow rate (current.)

---

Strictly speaking, it is all about the energy.  Energy is the product of power and time.  Since the time is the same for both the input side and the output side, the time cancels out and you can say that power in has to be greater than the power out.

If the power supply stored energy (like a battery backup system,) then the time on the input and the output aren't the same anymore and you have to work with energy.

A power supply doesn't store large amounts of energy, so we can just compare power rather than energy.

Comment: ... and just to mention that the 40 W figure is worst case at 100 V input and probably just for a second while powering up. After that the power drawn from the mains will be maybe 10 to 25% more than the power drawn by the 5 V device.

Comment: Correct, but liable to muddy the waters for the person asking the question.

Comment: Not as much as the hose in the garden will. d;^)

Comment: Excellent answer.  I forgot how current and voltage are related, but the water analogy was perfect.  That was a great refresher.  Listing the output in mA also threw me for a loop. Why not just show 2A?  Thanks for the detailed, quick response!

Comment: I also find it odd that the input is in amperes and the output is in milliamperes.  Neither side is precise to the milliampere, so that it would be perfectly reasonable for both to be in amperes.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the power transform is the same.
Ideally, the same power from input transfer to output. in reality you have power loss too.
P=V*I, when the output voltage is lower than the input voltage, you will be able to have higher output current.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways that the output current of a power supply can be greater than the input current.

The first way is that the power supply uses a step-down transformer. (Probably not for a USB supply, but it is one method nevertheless. In a step down transformer, the voltage is reduced by some ratio, but the current is increased by (approximatly) the same ratio. So, for example, if the voltage is halved, the current is approximately doubled.

A second way that the output current of a power supply may be greater than the input current occurs in a buck converter (or some similar converters). Here is a simplified schematic of how a buck converter works.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr0EmT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The switch is rapidly toggled on and off. When the switch is closed, current flows from the power supply, through the inductor L1 and through the Vout terminal to the load. When the switch is open, current continues to flow through the inductor and through the Vout terminal to the load, but the current comes from the ground through D1 then into L1. L1 doesn't want its current to change, so it "sucks" current up from the ground to compensate for the lack of current coming from V1.

It should be clear that the total current going to Vout and the load is the sum of the currents from V1 and the current comeing from the ground through D1. Hence the total current out is greater than the current supplied by the source.

Something similar to this (overly) simplified circuit is what is probably in your USB supply.

Answer (score 0):

Power adaptors, transformers, and power supplies pass power (voltage times current) not just voltage or just current.

If the power adaptor reduces the voltage, the current will increase to maintain the same power (actually, nothing is 100% efficient, so the output power will be a little less than the input power).